# unit digit of series containing factorial

Tags: number-theory

[UNIT DIGIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obP4p.jpg)

> The unit digit of the following expression
>   $$ (1!)^{99!} + (2!)^{98!} + (3!)^{97!} + (4!)^{96!} + \ldots + (99!)^{1!} $$

iam getting unit digit as  1 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 0 +-----+0  = 9 as answer am i correct

Comment: It is possible with a little learning to post mathematical expressions here.  See this [introduction to using math notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and its links to more detailed tutorial and reference material.

Comment: you please edit iam new to site

Comment: Even so you can ask a sensible question.  Improve your post by adding some explanation of how you approached this.  It may be that your thinking is perfectly correct, but Readers should not have to guess what you are thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I felt a little bit confusing about the derivation at first sight but I can say it is perfectly right.

The simple calculations are as follows:

$\bullet$ Since $98!~ mod4 = 0$, $2^{98!} mod10 =6$, it is like the cycle of $2 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 8 \rightarrow 6$.

$\bullet$ The unit digit of every power of 3!, which is 6, is 6.

$\bullet$ Since $96!~ mod2 = 0$, $(4!)^{96!} mod10 =6$, it is like the cycle of $4 \rightarrow 6 \rightarrow 4\rightarrow 6$.

$\bullet$ From $5!=120$ on, every factorial has its unit digit 0, so any power of them should have unit digit 0, which confirms your result.

Comment: yes thanks did same way